# How to get the old color theme in Eclipse Luna?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse Luna and for some reason they have removed the default light colored theme that I'm familiar with.

[image]

They've provided 4 theme options all of which are black:

[image]

I'm surprised that they dropped the old theme. Atleast it should have been kept as an option.

Questions:

- How do I get the old theme back without relying on theme plug-ins?
- If I have to resort to a plug-in like [eclipsecolorthemes](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/) which theme corresponds most closely to the eclipse default?

I have `Version: Luna RC1 Release (4.4.0RC1) Build id: 20140522-1310` for Linux

**Edit:**

I have tested and the same problem happens in:

1. Luna RC2
2. Luna RC3
3. ggts-3.6.0.M1

Comment: Did you restart your IDE after selecting,  i.e. classic?

Comment: Has Luna been released for public use? Because I still see the [official page](http://projects.eclipse.org/releases/luna) say that it's going to release on June 25th, 2014.

Comment: @RJ I guess the final release may be different. As of now I have `Version: Luna RC1 Release (4.4.0RC1) Build id: 20140522-1310`

Comment: On my Mac both the Classic and Mac styles are light. Luna RC 3

Comment: @KshitizSharma - Okay, I see that it's just the release candidate yet. The stable release is due on June 25th, 2014 as mentioned.

Comment: @greg-449 Do you have a download link to `RC3`? The latest release on the download page is `RC2`.

Comment: I am using the Eclipse SDK rather than one of the Eclipse packages (the SDK has just core Eclipse + JDT + PDE + Source). SDK downloads are at http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

Comment: @greg-449 I tried `RC3` SDK for Linux. It has the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to distinguish a syntax colors issue (Eclipse preferences) from a widget colors issue (Eclipse theme).
I think you're dealing with the second one.

**You are using a dark OS theme**, Eclipse is build on SWT that uses system widget. If an Eclipse (CSS) theme does not init a bright color for each widget then for it is used the color defined by your OS theme.
Only the `Dark` theme tries to set a dark color scheme for each widget; the `Classic`, `Default`, `GTK` etc. themes have always supposed that the user is using a bright OS theme so they *don't define* specific colors for each widget (and they never did it).

Moreover Eclipse 4.4+ switched to GTK3 by default, the SWT porting on GTK3 has still some rendering issues and some more limitations compared to the previous Eclipse versions based on GTK2 (you can notice them especially when switching to the Eclipse `Dark` theme).

Supposing that with your current configuration and Eclipse 4.3- you have the desired appearance, a workaround can be running Eclipse in GTK2-compatible mode by starting it with a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SWT_GTK3=0
./eclipse
```

If this doesn't solve your issue, you have to edit the desired CSS theme in `\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_*version*\css\` by adding a bunch of rules to init each relevant widget to a bright color scheme.

Comment: `adding rules to init each relevant widget` You're kidding right?

Comment: @KshitizSharma Sadly.. no, it's what I had to do some time ago to deliver the current `Dark` theme. Your use-case is exactly the opposite: dark environment with bright Eclipse GUI ;)

Comment: I was experiencing issues with the default theme (white font on white background) and gnome 3. The env variable fixed those as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly set the color scheme yourself, I haven't looked very closely into the new eclipse (still use an older version myself), but I found this which might be of help:

http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=790

http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/

Otherwise, maybe this answer can be of help:

You can reset to default color scheme in the Window>Preferences options page. This expample will be for resetting a theme usd for Java.

Navagate to Windows>Preferences>Java>Editor. Click on Syntax Coloring. Click "Restore Defaults" and "Apply". Then, navagate to General>Editors. Click on Text Editors. Click on "Restore Defaults" and "Apply".

I had the same issue and the above steps cleared up my problem. Also, the Show line numbers check box is on the last page from above.

Comment: `Click "Restore Defaults"` doesn't work as the screen shot in question is the new default.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question a bit. Could you look into the links I sent you? It might be a hassle setting all those settings yourself, but then you would have a default scheme of your own to use at any time...