# Eclipse Luna in Xubuntu 14.04: unreadable unselected items in Code Assist

Tags: eclipse, xubuntu

How I can fix this? In Xubuntu I have installed `Dorian Theme`.

In `Appearance` -> `Color and Fonts` I see `Content Assist background color` and `Content Assist foreground color`, but this not working for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated your theme **gtkrc** file. Usually themes can be found in `/usr/share/themes` folder.

Refer these post.

- [The selected entry in Eclipse content assist is unreadable because of colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424800/the-selected-entry-in-eclipse-content-assist-is-unreadable-because-of-colours)
- [How to change the highlight color in autocomplete box in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012176/how-to-change-the-highlight-color-in-autocomplete-box-in-eclipse)
- [eclipse content assist popup is unreadable on ambiance radiance theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62421/eclipse-content-assist-popup-is-unreadable-on-ambiance-radiance-theme)
- [eclipse colour scheme is terrible in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190062/eclipse-colour-scheme-is-terrible-in-ubuntu)
- [How to change tooltip background color in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity) - Do it for your theme i.e - **Dorian Theme**

Comment: Hm, no one working for me. I only can change theme... I think I can manually search for this color values in my `/usr/share/themes/dorian-theme-3.10/gtk-3.0/`. I `grep` for `tooltip` and I already change all this values - not effect..

Comment: change **gtkrc** file present in **gtkrc-2.0** folder. Eclipse uses gtk-2.0 by default

Comment: `/usr/share/themes/dorian-theme-3.10/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`: `gtk-color-scheme = "base_color:#0a0a0a\nfg_color:#cdcdcd\ntooltip_fg_color:#000000\nselected_bg_color:#154478\nselected_fg_color:#FFFFFF\ntext_color:#adadad\nbg_color:#1a1a1a\ntooltip_bg_color:#FFFFFF"` but my background in Eclipse tooltip not white.

Comment: Is this works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993206/how-to-get-the-old-color-theme-in-eclipse-luna